# Is there an infinite Carmichael numbers of this form $K.p^n+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, pseudoprimes

Carmichael numbers are these numbers that passes fermat test for any base from $1$ to $N-1$

EX : $a^{561} \equiv a \pmod {561} $  where $ 1 \le a \le 560 $

These numbers are infinite, and I have found many numbers of this form $K.p^n+1$  where $K \lt p^n$ and $p$ is prime, such as $(1729,46657,63973,101101,126217,278545,449065)$

But I was wondering if there are an infinitely many 
 Carmichael numbers of this  form $K.p^n+1$ or not ?

Note: $n=1$ is allowed

Comment: Maybe if you read through the proof that there are infinitely many Carmichaels you'll see whether the proof can be tweaked to get the result you're after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very likely there are infinitely many such Carmichael numbers. Consider the four polynomials:
$$\begin{array}{lcl}
P_1(x) & = & 6x+1 \\
P_2(x) & = & 12x+1 \\
P_3(x) & = & 18x+1 \\
P_4(x) & = & 36x^2 + 11x+1
\end{array}$$

All four polynomials have positive leading coefficient, are irreducible over integers and each of them attains at least two different prime values. Furthermore, for any prime $p$, the values of the polynomials at $x=p$ are not divisible by $p$. This implies these four polynomials satisfy the conditions of 
[Generalized Bunyakovsky conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture#Generalized_Bunyakovsky_conjecture) and thus there should be infinitely many values of $x$ for which all of them attain prime values simultaneously.

For each such $x$, [Korselt's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number#Korselt's_criterion) tells us that the product $$M=P_1(x)P_2(x)P_3(x)=1296x^3+396x^2+36x+1=36xP_4(x)+1$$ is a Carmichael number. At the same time, $36x<P_4(x)$ for positive integers $x$ so the number $M$ is also of the form $Kp^1+1$ for prime $p=P_4(x)$ and $K<p$.

Comment: but do we guarantee that there infinitely many values of $x$, such that : both of $P_1 (x), P_2 (x), P_3 (x), P_4 (x)$ are primes ? could you give me some values of $x$ that satisfy the above condition ? sorry for annoying.

Comment: That's precisely what the Generalized Bunyakovsky conjecture states: if the polynomials satisfy certain criteria (and I described why these four polynomials satisfy them), there would be infinitely many $x$ for which the polynomials are simultaneously prime. As of now, it is just a _conjecture_ (i.e. it has not been proven but there are good reasons to believe it to be true), thus my cautious wording at the beginning: "It is _very likely_" rather than "It is true". As for examples, $56$, $206$, $276$, $1280$ and $1490$ are the first five (e.g. $x=56$ corresponds to $N=228842209$).

Comment: ok sir, thank you very much, it is wonderful and very acceptable answer.